# .Net Micro Framework emulator is not recognized by Visual Studio after changing the framework

Tags: .net, emulation, .net-micro-framework

I developed a custom device emulator for .Net Micro Framework version 4.1.

This was working properly until I changed the target framework to 4.2. Even after I updated the assemblies used by the emulator from 4.1 to 4.2, the device doesn't show up as an available deployment option for the desired framework version. It is still registered as an emulator for .net MF 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command in the emulator project should force an update of the emulator registration information. This must be run with Visual Studio command prompt:

```
msbuild /target:RegisterEmulator  /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

a 4.1 emulator can't run 4.2 binaries.  You need to change the project for the emulator to 4.2 and rebuild.

The available emulators are found at 
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft.NETMicroFramework\4.1\Emulators.

You can add the same key for 4.2

Comment: My issue was making a project initially started as a 4.1 emulator, but later converted to a 4.2 emulator, recognized by VS as 4.2. Just rebuilding didn't fixed it so I searched in my hard drive for a file containing the GUID assigned to the emulator without much luck. In these days of xml files for everything I totally forgot to lookup in the system registry :-)